# clustering for data with too many features

Tags: r, clustering, feature-selection

I have a data set of information about different products that I want to cluster similare ones so I can do pricing on them. Each product have at least ten features that I can consider to differentiate between clusters. I wonder if clustering methods in R are able to handle too many features.

Comment: I don't think 10 features is a lot.. What are your features, scalars? Vectors? You need to be more specific in your question. It is too broad now.

Comment: well. some of them are categorical and sum are numeric. For example it depend on the raw material brand, time of day that it was produced, day of year ....

Answer (score 1):

Ten features is not "**too many**". 
You can performing clustering on these data without any problems! 
Nevertheless, when you pass correlated variables into a clustering algorithm, your final clusters could depends on how correlated the variables are. If the variables are highly correlated, you could drop one of them from the features set, since the variables behave in a very similar manner... So try at the beginning to check how the variables are correlated.